# Div Left & Right but also top and bottom centred?

Tags: css, html, alignment

So I'm attempting to create this effect where when the window is pulled big enough two divs align side by side but when made smaller the divs stack above each other and centred neatly.

So far I have this view.
[image: Image of centred view]

The CSS for the DIV wrapping the image is:

```
div.pararight {
width:451px; 
height:272px; 
margin:0px auto; 
position:relative;}
```

Titled 'Pararight' because when the screen is this wide the divs should sit by side with the image on right.

The CSS for the DIV wrapping the text is:

```
div.paraleft {
width:480px;
margin:0px auto;
position:relative;}
```

Named 'paraleft' as the text will align to the left.

It's also important to mention. I think, these 2 DIVs are wrapped in another DIV which is:

```
div.hitterbox {
width:100%; 
margin: 0px auto; 
font-family: sans-serif; 
font-size: 13pt; 
line-height:18pt}
```

Mainly because there will be multiple of these hitterbox div's down the page and it was easier to copy paste and change the HTML content, *don't need to explain that though I'm asking for your help!*

Finally another piece of information is that the container holding the hitterbox is another DIV which has the CSS:

```
div.pagecontent {
padding:10px; 
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size:12pt; 
position:static;
text-align:center;}
```

Finally the HTML for it all:

```
<div class="pagecontent">
<div class="hitterbox">
<div class="pararight"><img src="images/Macbook.png" width="451" height="272"  alt="Mac   Book"/></div>
<div class="paraleft">The Onscreen Text</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I put pararight above paraleft so it aligns up and down that way as you can see. The white page container of all the DIVs mentioned below is 1200px wide at the moment so enough room to sit both of these guys side by side.

What would I need to to make the text DIV move to the side of the image and the image to the right. I have used float:left, float:right in the respective DIVs but then when its shrunk down to create the stack effect they are shifted right and left respectively until the user shrinks the page down to 480px when the text will be centred but the image will still float slightly right.

What have I done wrong here? :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `display: inline-block`, then add `text-align: center` in the parent element.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gW8r2/1

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    text-align: center;
}

.parent > div {
    display: inline-block;
}

.a {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}

.b {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
```

This is a generalized solution. In your case, `.parent` would be `.hitterbox`, `.a` would be `.paraleft`, and `.b` would be `.pararight`.

Comment: No problem, that's what SO is for.